# What is the SQL syntax to add multiple rows of data in one time?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, sql-insert, bulkinsert

Here is my code and obviously there is something wrong with it.

```
INSERT INTO qdel(delno,delqty)
VALUES
(192,3422);
(1,2);
(203,20);
```

How to insert multiple rows of data in one statement?

Comment: You need to write three insert statements. And even **if** Oracle did support multi-row inserts, the rows need to be separated with a `,` not a `;`. The semicolon `;` terminates the complete **statement**

Answer (score 2):

You trying to insert mutiple row in same table.

But your process is not valid in oracle

Try like this

```
INSERT ALL
 INTO qdel(delno,delqty) VALUES (192,3422)
 INTO qdel(delno,delqty) VALUES (1,2)
 INTO qdel(delno,delqty) VALUES (203,20)
select * from dual
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine. But I consider there may be some more convenient way.

Comment: I have recently seen a rise in the usage of `insert all` - I never understood how that is more convenient than simply writing three insert statements because it doesn't remove the necessity to qualify the columns for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO qdel(delno, delqty)
    select 192, 3422 from dual union all
    select 1, 2 from dual union all
    select 203, 20 from dual;
```